# Paypal Express Checkout / React - Send Product Information

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal-sandbox, paypal

I'm working on a shop app that I want to use Paypal with to checkout.

I have installed this very nifty React implementation of the Express Checkout Button - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paypal-express-checkout

After setting up my merchant account, developer app, and sandbox accounts it was working right away.

The only issue I'm running into is that my app has a built-in cart; Keeping track of what items the user intends to purchase and what options they have selected for each one ( Color, size, quantity, etc ), and the seller needs to know this information so they can ship the correct products.

I was wondering if there is a way I could send some additional information with the purchase to let the seller know what products the user has purchased and what options they have selected. If somehow I could just send one extra string to appear in the seller's account I could easily attach the user's cart info.

Sorry if this is a noob-ish question. I am still fairly new to web-dev.

Comment: why don't you just save all the cart information in the database when they attempt to pay and have a field `paid:false` and when paypal informs you that the payment has been made, change the field to `true`. Then in that you can have as many key values as you want

Comment: @serendipity I guess I'm not sure what you mean..paid is a boolean value.

Comment: Yes. but in database you can save other values too

Comment: Then you can just filter by paid

Comment: @serendipity I am trying to send the information to the sellers paypal to see when my client is reviewing orders, I am not displaying orders on the site. I could definitely do something like what you're saying, but I am 100% sure there is a way to send product information with a Paypal purchase (which is what I'm asking about.)

Comment: @serendipity Also, after some attempts at other workarounds, it's kind of sketchy to store purchases yourself. Someone could close the browser, still pay their money, but not wait long enough for paypal to let you know the payment has been made. Leaving them thinking their getting a product but the seller has no way of knowing they purchased anything.

Comment: I don't really know how paypal informs the server whether the purchase has been made but it's usually independent of whether the client is closed or not and it should be due to the reason you have mentioned. In the payment module I use there is a notification url that you can define where you will receive the results.

Comment: @serendipity ah I see why we're on different pages. The Paypal button I am using is client based. It doesn't interact with my server at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found in the documentation that you can send a table of items using `item_list`. With each item you can attach a name, as well as a list of options ( size, color, etc,. ) But I cannot find how to format this list in the documentation, and [no one seems to know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46243951/how-to-define-a-transtactions-items-options).

So as a workaround I am just attaching the options to the name so the buyer and seller can see a full list of every item and their options.

Here's what it looks like in your paypal transaction - 
[image]

If anyone needs to use this [I forked the node package](https://github.com/quangogage/react-paypal-express-checkout) above and implemented this functionality. Hopefully this can help someone trying to implement paypal into their react shop.